# Problems with UTF-8/ISO-8859-1 encoding on Windows --> Unix

Tags: java, windows, unix, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I've written a program that has to deal with the Swedish letters `å` `ä` and `ö`. I wrote it on a Windows computer and everything works perfectly fine there. But when I tried to run the program in Unix the Swedish letters don't show and the program doesn't work when dealing with the Swedish letters. It's in java by the way.

Any ideas what to do, so it works when running on Unix?

Comment: when you say unix you mean linux, right? what distribution are you using? did you set up utf-8 correctly for your distro? (that's what I missed when I had the same problem some time ago)

Comment: Yes. What do you mean by distro?

Comment: "distro" means "distribution", such as Ubuntu, openSuSE, debian, ...

Comment: My program reads from a textfile and takes out the words and organize them in a way in different files. I hash the words so I can get fast access to them. When I use the program I give it an input which I want to find in the files. The program hashes that word but cannot find it in the files.

Comment: Ok, do you have streams?

Comment: Yes, using different streams as RandomAccessFile, BufferedWriter and DataOutputStream.

Comment: What about some buffered reader?

Comment: I have tried to read words and strings by converting them to a byte array also as you can see in the code below, but it doesn't print out å, ä and ö.

(Kattio is a class we use that uses BufferedReader)
word = kattio.getWord();
byteRep=word.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
System.out.println(new String(byteRep, "ISO-8859-1"));

Comment: @AndreasHenning What do you mean by setting up utf-8 for my distro?

Comment: Some guidance on multi-platform unicode programming can be found here: http://www.utf8everywhere.org

Comment: I trust you're aware that ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8 are two different character encodings, and that they have incompatible representations for å, ä, and ö. And Windows tends to use UTF-16 rather than UTF-8 for Unicode, yet another incompatible encoding.

Comment: there's not enough information here to help you. Are you sure you even have a font with those characters? It is it console program or a GUI?

Comment: It'd be really funny if, at the end, it'll turn out that you uploaded the textfile to the UNIX box as a text file (ASCII), rather than binary.....

Comment: Didn't you satisfied with the answers here? Please accept answers.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like with encoding

```
FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath()), fileEncoding)
```

where `fileEncodig == "UTF-8"` or other encoding, also usefull to add `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` system property or programmatically

```
System.setProperty("file.encoding", fileEncoding);
```

You can use the same encoding to `String#getBytes(fileEncoding)` or `String` constructor with `getBytes`. The example of encoding and decoding symbols using `UTF-8` charset:

```
new String (value.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"),"UTF-8");
```

I used this also for reading UTF-8 bundled resources.

The same thing use for `FileOutputStream`

```
FileOutputStream(file.getAbsolutePath()), fileEncoding)
```

Comment: Thanks! We've tried that already, but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @Yvonne You can't make difference until you can see UTF-8 decoded symbols.